# Stop bubbling events in WinForms

Tags: .net, winforms, events, event-bubbling

I have a (custom) `MyTextbox`. MyTextbox in on (custom) `MyPanel`, and the panel is on the `MyForm`.

When the user edits text in MyTextbox and press, say "DEL" the MyForm recieves the `_KeyDown` event...

But on the form I programmed an other action to do when pressing on "Delete", so it performs the Form action along with the textbox selection deleting...

How to stop the event propagation from the textbox to the form, or identify the textbox as the sender of the event?

PS.
I can't turn *KeyPreview* to "False" for multiple reasons, I need to find another solution.

PPS.
Imagine the MS Word editor in whitch you have a editable "rectangle" ... If you edit the text in the rectangle (in edition mode the rectangle is selected), your "Del" should delete chars in the rectangle, if not, it should delete the rectangle itself... (if the rectangle is selected).

In my case, I am in the edition mode in rectangle I selected some text, but when I press DEL instead of deleting the text, is removes the rectangle itself....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the form's KeyPreview property is set to False, which is usually the default for a form.

A possible work-around if you have `KeyPreview=true` is to check the active control and filter the Form's handling of the key events:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) {
  if (ActiveControl.GetType() != typeof(TextBox)) {
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't turn KeyPreview to "False" for multiple reasons, I need to find another solution.

Comment: Even if MyTextBox in on MyPanel, and MyPanel is on the MyForm, when I press the "Del" button in MyTextBox the "sender" on the MyForm_KeyDown event appears to be the "MyForm" itself... (

Comment: because first of all the "Del" will be catched in the Form, and only then it will go to the textBox... (

Comment: @serhio Since `KeyPreview=true`, the form will process the event first, which is why I added a "filter" to the form's event in my example.

Comment: OK I see, I thought that you compared the type of "sender", sorry. But actually my active control is MyPanel... And not all the events from MyPanel I should ignore, only the Del events that came from "MyTextBox" (private control of the MyPanel)

Comment: @serhio Then how are you typing in the textbox if the panel has the focus?

Comment: @serhio Can you filter on the panel instead of the textbox then?

Comment: the hierarchy is the following
((MyForm.ActiveControl as MyPanel).ActiveControl as SplitContainer).ActiveControl = MyTextbox

Comment: If myTextbox is focused (in edition) the "DEL" should "behave" IN the box, if not, "del" should delete some objets on the panel...

Comment: Imagine the MS Word editor in whitch you have a editable "rectangle" ... If you edit the text in the rectangle, your "del" should delete chars in the rectangle, if not, it should delete the rectangle itself...

Comment: @serhio Your "controls" need to set a flag somehow that the form can use to determine whether or not to process the delete key.  You haven't shared any code so it's hard to offer more help than that.